# What should I look for in the written estimate provided by the technician for musical instrument servicing?

Tags: instruments, maintenance

If the technician for musical instrument servicing provides with an estimate or explanation of the work that will be done, a written estimate will help understand what work is being done and how much it will cost.

What should I look for in the written estimate provided by the technician for musical instrument servicing?

Comment: Surely this will vary a lot from one sort of instrument to another. Compare guitar with saxophone, for example, not a lot of common ground.

Comment: Adding onto @Tim it's impossible to answer until we know what kind of instrument we are talking about.

Comment: I usually just establish that the technician is someone I can trust to do a good job and to accurately tell me what needs to be done. I do that partly by asking colleagues who they recommend. If I were to have any doubt, I might ask a competing technician for a second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

An estimate for any kind of handwork, not just musical, needs to contain several things:

- a complete listing of exactly what the technician intends to do
- an estimate of the necessary time
- the hourly rate for the technician
- the costs for parts and other material
- the time the servicing will take
- depending on where you are, possibly any legal requirements

It's also important to discuss with the technician exactly why this work needs to be done.

Probably more important is some information that will **not** be on the estimate: the reputation of the person who is going to be doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of knowing even what kind of instrument this is, I can only be just so specific.  @PiedPiper has a good answer for things to look for on the estimate.  Beyond that, your best bet is to ask musicians for references/recommendations.  You might find, for example, one guitar "expert" online who will accidentally destroy your instrument, but five professional players may all suggest the same technician by word-of-mouth.  If it's a band instrument or orchestra instrument, you might contact a high school with an instrumental program and ask who they use.